# dataset wont update database

Tags: c#, dataset

I'am trying to update database after row has been deleted from dataset like this:

```
SqlCommand mySelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from NameDB", c);
                SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySelectCommand);
                TheNewDataSet ds = new TheNewDataSet();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "NameDB");
DataRow[] FilteredRow = ds.Tables["NameDB"].Select("PName like '" + listBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'");
                foreach (DataRow drr in FilteredRow)
                {
                    ds.Tables["NameDB"].Rows.Remove(drr);
                }
                mySqlDataAdapter.Update(ds, "NameDB");
                c.Close();
```

And nothing happened to database, rows not deleted. According to debugger rows filtered correctly and deleted from DataSet normally. Where is mistake?

Comment: What is `TheNewDataSet` ?

Comment: It's dataset created via DataSet Wizard from existing database in vs 2012

Comment: AH, you must be the last one using Datasets instead of proper programming. Anyhow, yo ucall the wrong method. See my answer.

Comment: Can u provide guide what to use instead of Datasets?

Comment: And here we go - another clueless person voting to close on an obvious  programming error. "Too localized"? Why you not close ALL queries for help, they ALL are "localized" to a specific error made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first - it is not the dataset doing updates. NEVER EVER. It is the Adapter. The DataSet does not talk to the database.

But: you dont delete the rows, you - kill them (rows.remove).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13(v=vs.80).aspx

You should not use REMOVE but DELETE, which keeps the row with a status to delete it. THe way you do it you remove it, so the adapter never sees it. With ".Delete" the adpater sees the row as deleted, so it can act upon it.

Comment: My guess - change `ds.Tables["NameDB"].Rows.Remove(drr);` to `ds.Tables["NameDB"].Rows.Delete(drr);`.

Comment: Now, if the adapter is properly configured, it will issue delete commands.

Comment: No such method. Done through indexOf. get id of Row id = ds.NameDB.Rows.IndexOf(drr); and then del it                     ds.NameDB.Rows[id].Delete();

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing insert/update/delete commands on the sqldataadapter?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx

Comment: Actually he misses the rows.

Comment: AH, whover made a +1 - LEARN BEFORE VOTING. The ".Remove" removes the row from the table, so the adapter never sees it. The correct solution is to call "delete" not "remove". Seems the person answering - and the one upvoting - never used what they comment on. Sorry, -1.

Comment: Great. Swarm intelligence - the factually wrong answer gets marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today at work, so I would like to answer what I understood, so that this could be of some help in the future for others as well as myself.

From what I understood today, .Remove will take the rows of visually from the grid, but would not mark them as the rows to be deleted when you do AcceptChanges to save the changes to the database. As TomTom mentioned, you should use .Delete instead, which will mark those rows as the one's that needs to be deleted when persisting. If you debug your program and see the dataset in visualizer(?), you could see the difference. If I am correct, .Delete will have the rows marked with exclamation, and .Remove, I think just removes.